# Eclipse CDT - Treat 'char' as unsigned

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a legacy project for an old compiler into which we pass a compiler flag (something like -DCHAR_AS_UNSIGNED) to treat the 'char' type as unsigned. The compiler is a really old proprietary one we run separately in the command line instead of through Eclipse. There's a lot of old code we have which uses unsigned char* for strings rather than char*. By default, Eclipse handles this as it should and warns that passing unsigned char* to routines expecting char* is not right. Is there a way to have Eclipse ignore these and treat it like our compiler does?

Comment: Maybe turn off code analysis? `Preferences->C/C++->Code Analysis` (I always have it turned off because the compiler gives good warnings)

Comment: That's a pretty big hammer unfortunately. It's quite handy to see some errors in real time as I work. I have changed the "invalid arguments" setting in the Code Analysis settings to an "info" as opposed to an "error", but that also runs the risk of masking an error until compile time.

Comment: The C++ standard says `char` may, at the implementation's discretion, act as a signed or unsigned integer type, but in either case, it's still a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`. That means it's not valid to pass an `unsigned char*` to a function expecting a `char*`. If your compiler accepts this, it's a nonstandard extension supported by your compiler, which CDT does not support.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've been able to achieve was to add a globally defined symbol to the project ( Project -> Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols ) which defines `char` as `unsigned char`.

For the most part it works, since most of the legacy code I'm concerned with doesn't already use unsigned char (which would screw with this workaround). It even seems to behave well with the typedefs we have for integral types of specific widths (`U8` for instance is defined as `typedef unsigned char U8`). This solution will not work well where `unsigned char` is used in files as it'll get expanded to `unsigned unsigned char`.